# Indexing a C# Datatable to search like you would with a SQL query

Tags: c#, database, linq, datatable

I couldn't find any similar questions in Stack Overflow

Is there a way to create a virtual SQL database with indexes in memory? Or maybe a built in function for creating indexes on datatables to quickly searching a column in a table multiple times? Trying to compare each row of table A against the indexed entry in table B (rather than looping through every row of table B completely for each row in Table A).

Right now I'm creating a dictionary<T,int> index where T is the typeof the column being indexed, and int is the row. That way if I create an index, I cycle through all rows of the table and create a dictionary key on the column (with the dictionary value being the row number). This works for unique primary keys, and I've used a variation with int lists if there are multiple rows for a given key.

This works when trying to find the exact value in another table, but not if I want to perform a comparison and find all int keys greater than a specific value. I could probaby reinvent the wheel with a sorted binary search tree (especially since the table data would be static), but would rather use an existing solution without the risk of introducing my own code errors.

Comment: Why are you trying to create a _virtual SQL database with indexes in memory_? Do you have some "measured" performance problem?

Comment: I'm working with datatables and want to efficiently search through them (they in turn are built from SQL queries). Building a generic system which allows 2 SQL queries to be passed in as parameters (run against two separate databases that cannot talk directly to each other), a specific column from each table is the key to be compared, and then any other matching columns between the queries are compared to make sure they match. Currently the number of rows being compared each run is in the millions. 

But I also want to perform value checks on a second column in case a match isn't found.

Comment: All of the queries and comparisons take 10-20 minutes to run, and I just want to get the efficiency up using existing tools/packages.

Comment: Use a sorted `List<T>` with `BinarySearch` maybe?

Comment: So you get data from a well-indexed (or at least well-indexable) environment —a database— into non-indexed memory data and then you find out you're missing indexes. Sounds like a design that needs reevaluation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create in-memory SQLite Database and then you can use all of its benefits.
https://sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html